# How to display a SVG image as a UIImage with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, svg, uiimage

I need to change the icon of a GMSMarker (on Google Maps) to an SVG image (which I'm requesting from the web), any idea how to do this? Ive seen a few libraries which can do this but unsure how to use them! I basically need to convert an SVG image to a UIImage!

Comment: Not completely sure what you are trying to do, but would it be an option to use a WKWebView and just load the svg in that? If not, maybe there is a way to use a webview to decode the svg into an image, and use that...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I had to put this in an answer, so sorry if it sounds more like a comment:

Anyway, You said you need to convert a SVG image to a UIImage. I've never done this, but I have created a UIImage from NSData before. Perhaps there is a way to convert the SVG to NSData and then to UIImage (you might have to convert it from SVG to jpeg and then to NSData, I'm not sure. I would need to dig up the project where I did that.)

Or maybe you could use the UIImage initializer called init?(contentsOfFile path: String). This initializer takes one parameter, which is a String that represents the path to the image.

Again, I've not tried any of this yet. Just trying to be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Two potential methods.

First, and easiest, is to export the SVG to PNG format. Most apps will allow that modification - on Mac you can use Sketch, for example. But it takes away the advantage of resolution-independent nature of SVG so it's not ideal. You could export PNG for various resolutions and ship 1x/2x/3x with your app.

The other option is to create a custom class derived from `UIView`, and override `drawRect`. In that, use functions to draw the SVG, which you can look at by opening the SVG (it's readable, like a text file, as you would know). The `drawRect` would look something like this:

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 11.5, y: 17.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 28.5, y: 17.5))
// etc - you get the idea..
bezierPath.closePath()
```

Now, when you insert the custom UIView, it will automatically draw itself. This is the approach used by PaintCodeApp (see www.paintcodeapp.com). You could use the trial version of the app to generate the code, or buy the app.